# ard-reset-arduino resetting Leonardo/Micro via USB works on OSX, fails on Ubuntu

Tags: usb, arduino-leonardo, bootloader, avrdude, reset

I'm trying to program a Leonardo (actually a Micro ATmega32U4) via the command line using USB.  Schematically, I'm doing `ard-reset-arduino` followed by a `sleep 1` and an `avrdude` command.

This works reliably on my Mac (OSX 10.12.1, avrdude v6.3), but bombs out on Ubuntu (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2, avrdude v6.1) with the message:

```
.avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Update: I believe this is actually due to a failure to get the atmega32u4 into the bootloader.  See `update` at the bottom of this post...

Has anyone seen this?  Any suggestions for debugging strategies or things to try?

#### Details on the Mac:

Here is the command line with results under OS X:

```
$ ./ard-reset-arduino --verbose --caterina /dev/cu.usbmodem1411 && sleep 1 && /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -V -D -p atmega32u4 -C /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -c avr109 -b 9600 -P /dev/cu.usbmodem1411 -U flash:w:./leds_test.ino.leonardo.hex:i
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port /dev/cu.usbmodem1411
/dev/cu.usbmodem1411 has come back after reset

Connecting to programmer: .
Found programmer: Id = "CATERIN"; type = S
    Software Version = 1.0; No Hardware Version given.
Programmer supports auto addr increment.
Programmer supports buffered memory access with buffersize=128 bytes.
Programmer supports the following devices:
    Device code: 0x44

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9587 (probably m32u4)
avrdude: reading input file "./leds_test.ino.leonardo.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (9146 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.70s

avrdude: 9146 bytes of flash written
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:CB, H:D8, L:FF)
avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

#### Details on Ubuntu:

Here is the command line with results under Ubuntu.  Except for the pathnames, all of the options are the same as under OSX:

```
$ /boot/ard-reset-arduino --verbose --caterina /dev/ttyACM0 && sleep 1 && /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/../avrdude -V -D -p atmega32u4 -C /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/../avrdude.conf -c avr109 -b 9600 -P /dev/ttyACM0 -U flash:w:/boot/leds_test.ino.leonardo.hex:i
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port /dev/ttyACM0
Waiting for /dev/ttyACM0 to come back
Waiting for /dev/ttyACM0 to come back
Waiting for /dev/ttyACM0 to come back
Waiting for /dev/ttyACM0 to come back
Waiting for /dev/ttyACM0 to come back
Waiting for /dev/ttyACM0 to come back
Waiting for /dev/ttyACM0 to come back
Waiting for /dev/ttyACM0 to come back
/dev/ttyACM0 has come back after reset

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

#### Postscript

Just to make sure I hadn't borked the bootloader somehow, I moved the Leonardo/Micro back to the OSX and re-ran the reset / programming sequence under OSX.  It worked without error, so I conclude that the resident bootloader is intact.

#### Update

I believe the real problem is that under Ubuntu, `ard-reset-arduino` fails to put the Leonardo into the bootloader.

Here's why I believe this is the problem: the resident sketch makes the onboard LEDs blink.  On the Mac, running `ard-reset-arduino` makes the blinking stop for about 8 seconds.  On Ubuntu, the LEDs continue to blink without interruption after the `ard-reset-arduino` command returns.

#### Update 2

Here's an even simpler Python program that resets the Leonardo under OSX but not under Ubuntu.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(sys.argv[1], 1200)
ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm somewhat embarrassed as to the source of the problem.  It wasn't an OSX vs Ubuntu issue.

Rather, on the Ubuntu system, there was an another application that was holding the USB port open, so attempts to reset the Leonardo were failing.

Rather than delete this post out of shame, I'm leaving it here in case someone else stumbles across the same problem.